# OnRowUpdating event and TextBox_TextChanged Event not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I am showing the Grid with one link button, if i click that, it will show a GridView like a dialog(Popup).That Grid is,

```
<asp:GridView ID="HistoryGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="True"
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" AllowPaging="True" Font-Size="9pt" BackColor="White"
        BorderColor="#DEDFDE" Width="100%" BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="Vertical" PageSize="10" 
        OnRowEditing="HistoryGrid_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="HistoryGrid_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="HistoryGrid_RowUpdating"
        OnRowUpdated="HistoryGrid_RowUpdated" OnRowDataBound="HistoryGrid_RowDataBound" >
```

and the HistoryGrid has one Column contains TextBox.

```
<Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField><EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="DateTxt" CssClass="datepick" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="DateTxt_TextChanged" Font-Size="8.3pt" ></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
```

Now the Problem Is the TextBox_TextChanged Event and The HistoryGrid_RowUpdating event are not Firing.

Code Behind

```
protected void DateTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //code
}

protected void HistoryGrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
 //code
}
```

Comment: Check `AutoEventWireup ` is true in your page directive.

Comment: ya it is true already

Answer (score 0):

Use `ItemTemplate` instead of `EditItemTemplate` :

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="DateTxt" CssClass="datepick" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="DateTxt_TextChanged" Font-Size="8.3pt" ></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Whatever it is,if  i changed the text in TextBox the gridView(Popup) got Closed.and the event not fired

Comment: You can refer this http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/show/3026/textbox-change-event-inside-gridview